# Catch Home button event from BT remote controller on OSX mac app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, bluetooth

I have a BT remote controller 3.0 : [http://www.amazon.com/Satechi-MediaRemote-Bluetooth-Multi-Media-Control/dp/B00824948U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00824948U)

This remote can control any OS X app with standard medias events (NX_KEYTYPE_PLAY, NX_KEYTYPE_EJECT, etc.) and with this callback settings :

```
CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap,
                kCGTailAppendEventTap,
                kCGEventTapOptionDefault,
                CGEventMaskBit(NX_SYSDEFINED),
                tapEventCallback,
                (__bridge void *)(self));
```

But NO event is sent to my callback when I click on HOME button.

The button can usually control HOME event on AppleTV or iOS devices (and it's work fine on them with my remote controller).

How catch home event ?
Thank you for any help ...